# Inline CSS from CMS

Tags: php, html, css

This question is purely out of curiosity. 
I am very picky over the neatness of my code and I hate using inline styles, however I have found a use case where I don't see any way to not implement them.

I am building a portion in my CMS which allows users to create multiple page sections with a lot of customisation, a page may look like

```
[    section A    ]    <--- Has an image, custom margins and padding set for content
[    section B    ]  
[    section C    ]    <--- custom margins and paddings set on this section
```

At the moment I have 3 database tables, one which supports basic information on the section such as a media link, title, subtitle etc.   Another which supports toggle options such as bleeding the overflow of the container, aligning text horizontally/vertically and then a third table which stores information on specific values for that table, i.e. the padding or custom margins set on text, or the zoom %age of an image.

Right now, when my page loads I pull all the data back for each section and iterate through an array assigning the styles inline with my elements with PHP:

```
function build_left_section($section) {
// Echo the standard section piece
echo '<section class="section_wrapper section_overflow" style="background:'.$section['section_color'].'; height:'.$section['height'].'px">';
echo '<div class="content row">';
      $this->get_borders($section);
echo '
     <div id="left_col" class="image_column grid_6 ' . $this->get_width($section, 'left') . '">
        <img id="image" src="'. $section['media_link'] .'" alt="'. $section['tags'] .'" style="margin-left:'. $section['image_x'] .'%; margin-top:'. $section['image_y'] .'%; width:'. $section['image_zoom'] .'%;">
     </div>

     <div id="right_col" class="text_column grid_6 ' . $this->get_width($section, 'right') . '">
        <div class="text_move" style="margin-left:'.$section['text_x'].'%; margin-top:'.$section['text_y'].'%">
            <div class="text_wrap '.$this->get_text_alignment($section).'" style="padding-left:'.$section['text_padding'].'px; padding-right:'.$section['text_padding'].'px;">
                '.$this->get_text($section).'
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     ';
}
```

I hate how messy this code looks, and I'm sure there are some considerable performance drawbacks due to it bulking the size of my HTML doc, I also read somewhere that it may incur cache problems.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I could achieve the same result more effectively?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could write (parts of...) stylesheets dynamically as well and include a customized stylesheet..

Comment: A customised stylesheet for each section? Wouldnt that create a huge amount of requests on page load??

Comment: css makes sense if you're going to be re-using rules, or applying a particular value globally. but most of your stuff seems to be single-use values. unless your margin-left value (say) only allows 3 different values, then you should define 3 different css rules and just use that classname instead of an inline style.

Comment: @AlexSims No, for a specific user, no need to do it by section. You could even write that as a real css file and only re-write it when the user changes something.

Comment: I wish it only used 3 values but my client has requested so much customisation that the likelihood is almost all sections will be unique in terms of their margins (believe me I have tried to suggest that compromise)

Comment: Instead of having infinite margins and paddings, could you have a set number of margin / padding options that could be set by changing classes in place of inline css.

Comment: @misterManSam that was one solution I proposed but it was rejected by my client. He needs the infinite scaling margins and image zooms so he can customise a section exactly how he wants too

Comment: I handle other aspects in that manner though.  It looks like their isn't going to be another way! :(

Comment: This is where you tell your client that if he wants to customize every tiny little pixel, that he should go to school and learn how to become a web developer himself.

Comment: God bless clients :/

Comment: [PHP variables - interesting](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/)?

Comment: The only thing I can think of to do here is to create a css.php file (essentially a css file with .php extension).  There are a few articles on here how to do it, but it isn't exactly best practice, and is kind of a nasty way of doing it too.  But then, you could include variables in your CSS that can be attributed to your database.

Comment: @Hashem yup unfortunately Us engineers propose viable solutions but they see no compromise even though I can guarantee I'll be pulled up on it in future

Comment: Just a comment on comments: anyone working on custom CMS based solutions (eg Wordpress themes) knows that this is pretty common and done every single day. As a matter of fact, it's the foundation of WordPress customizer

Comment: @michael this projection has been thé job from hell but unfortunately I need the money haha

Comment: @AlexSims - Fabio's method is probably much better, but you could look into my comment and misterManSam's comment about a css.php.

Comment: Both nice ideas but I do think fabios is probably a cleaner approach to achieving it.  Thanks for the input all, was interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common scenario in custom CMS, you can do it like this:

Move your inline styles to an internal sheet. For example, this part:

```
<div id="left_col" class="image_column grid_6 ' . $this->get_width($section, 'left') . '">
        <img id="image" src="'. $section['media_link'] .'" alt="'. $section['tags'] .'" style="margin-left:'. $section['image_x'] .'%; margin-top:'. $section['image_y'] .'%; width:'. $section['image_zoom'] .'%;">
     </div>
```

becomes:

```
<div id="left_col" class="image_column grid_6 ' . $this->get_width($section, 'left') . '">
        <img class="my_image" src="'. $section['media_link'] .'" alt="'. $section['tags'] .'" />
     </div>
```

Now, in your page you can call the internal CSS like this:

```
margin-left:'. $section['image_x'] .'%; 
margin-top:'. $section['image_y'] .'%; 
width:'. $section['image_zoom'] .'%;"
```

and that's it, cleaner re-usable code.

Also, I have noticed you're abusing div IDs. Try to work with classes and be sure to close tags properly (in this sample, I closed the image tag)

Comment: Perfect, thanks fabio I'll try and implement that.  As for the div ids they're something that slipped through my fingers. I know they should really only be used for binding js events to elements and classes should be used for styles :)